# React Native Router Flux - Move navbar above tabs (Android)?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have a Tabbed Navigation scene coded like so:

```
<Scene
key="parent"
tabs
title="Parent Title"
>
  <Scene
    key="tab1"
    tabBarLabel="Tab 1"
  >
  <Scene
    key="tab2"
    tabBarLabel="Tab 2"
  >
</Scene>
```

On Android, this generates a view with a white navbar on the top of the screen, then a row of tabs (the tab bar), and then another navbar beneath the tabs.  I'd ideally like to just have the navbar at the top, then the row of tabs, and then my content (no 2nd navbar).  Is that possible?

Comment: Tried to put `hideNavBar={true}` on the tabs themself?

Comment: Yep, that removes ALL (including the one at the top) the navbars unfortunately...